# Community users able to change case record type

Tags: case, lightning-community

I have created 2 case record types. But, community users are able to change record type in community using this button[image]

How can I restrict community users from changing record type? Is there a setting to disable this for community users? I cannot write validation rule because there is workflow rule to update case record type on meeting certain criteria.

Comment: Have you tried removing the button from layout?

Answer (score 3):

Do the followings:

- Create a separate layout for community users(if you don't have one yet).
- Remove the **Change Record Type** button from that page layout.
- Assign the layout to the community profile.
- Make the **Record Type** field read-only from the community users
  profile.